# Ridiculously large amounts of RAM used (by lightdm)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, memory, swap, lightdm

Lately, my Arch setup is experiencing some problems. For one, a command `Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch` takes up about 25% of RAM (htop tells me this). Also, around 2GB of swap is being used. How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: This could be a memory leak. File a bug report.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov With? Because I just noticed that while the lightdm process continues to take more than 2 GB of RAM, killing picom (the compositor) brings down swap usage to 350M